# ~999 problems and votes are every one

Tags: bug, voting

Coming onto the site this morning, I was surprised to find that apparently every single one of our questions has -999 score.

On a second look, it turns out they actually have ~999 score.

This must be some kind of bug: when I vote on the post, the score returns to normal with my vote added.

A post:

[image: A post showing ~999 score]

The same post when voted on:

[image: A post which I have voted on, showing the correct score]

This seems strange; it's such an obvious bug that no doubt someone would have brought it up before me, so I have some suspicion that it's client-side. Still, can someone take a look?

Comment: Works for me. Do you see the same thing in another browser, in an incognito window, on another computer, etc.? Do you have any extensions/userscripts/… that could be acting up?

Comment: @Gilles Incognito, yes, and all extensions are disabled (I've checked) in incognito, so it can't be an extension.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.  How odd!  Do you see this on the front page too, or only on the question pages?  And what about meta?  And does it happen on any other sites or just WB?

Comment: @MonicaCellio All beta sites (i.e. same design as this one). Also happens on other computers. Not on the front page, not on meta.

Comment: Are you still admin ?

Comment: @Vincent nope, I reinstalled chrome and that fixed itself